# Removiendo data atributo y agregandolo dinamicamente con jquery pero aun siguen en el dom?

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de comprobar errores del lado del servidor y este me traera un numero dependiendo del tipo de error, el problema esta en que al editar quito y pongo un data atributo para luego comprobarlo con el focus, ya he probado con lo que esta comentado, pero no logro hacer que funcione, cuando uso el data

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.albaran', function () {
            var albaran = $(this).val();
            var input = $(this, '.albaran');


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("AlbaranValidar", "Inicio")',
                    data: { 'Albaran': albaran },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //input.removeAttr('data-error');
                        //input.removeData('error', null)
                        //input.data('error', data);
                        //input.attr('data-error', data);
                        //input.removeData('error', null)
                        //input.data('error', data);
                        input.removeAttr('data-error');
                        input.attr('data-error', data);
                    },
                    error: function (r) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
        });



        $(document).on('focus', '.albaran', function () {
            console.log($(this).data('error'));
            if ($(this).data('error') == 1) {
               $(this).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'El campo no puede estar vacio' });
            }

        });
```

el controlador

```
    public int ValidarAlbaran(string Albaran)
    {
        int AlbaranError = 0;

        if (Albaran == "" || Albaran == null)
        {
            AlbaranError = 1;
        }
        else if (Albaran.Length > 10)
        {
            AlbaranError = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt64(Albaran);
                AlbaranError = 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                AlbaranError = 2;
            }
        }
        return AlbaranError;
    }
```

hago un console.log pero me sigo trayendo el primer data que ya te.

Si el campo no tiene error me trae el data en 0 pero si lo edito y el error es mayor a caracteres aceptado trae 1 pero escribo y se cambia en el dom pero en el console.log sigue siendo 0

**Edicion En respuesta a Alvaro Montoro**

```
        $(document).on('focus', '.albaran', function () {

            console.log($(this).attr('data-error').toString()); //con este me imprimo el numero
            console.log($(this).attr('data-error')) // con este no;

            if ($(this).attr('data-error').toString() == "1") {
                console.log('entro al if del focus')
                $(this).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'El campo no puede estar vacio' });
            }
        });
```

no entra a la condicion del focus

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `console.log(data)` en el success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es más un problema de concepto. El valor del data-atributo `data-error` sí se actualiza con el código que tienes aquí:

```
input.removeAttr('data-error');
input.attr('data-error', data);
```

El problema es que luego, en el controlador del evento `focus`, lo estás intentando leer con el método `.data()` de jQuery:

```
$(this).data('error')
```

En la documentación de [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) se especifica que los data-atributos sólo se acceden/leen una vez y luego sus valores son guardados y no se acceden o mutan de nuevo (jQuery guarda los valores internamente). Y ahí es donde está el problema: con `.data()` estás accediendo a una "caché interna" de jQuery y no al valor del data-atributo en sí (en el DOM). Para acceder a dicho valor, tendrás que utilizar `.attr()`.

Entonces para que te funcione lo que ya tienes, sólo tienes que cambiar un poco el código del `focus` para hacer `.attr("data-error")` en lugar de `.data("error")` (y recuerda que se leerá como una cadena):

```
        ...
        console.log($(this).attr('data-error'));
        if ($(this).attr('data-error') == "1") {
        ...
```

---

En esta demo puedes ver como se actualiza y se lee el valor correctamente:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.albaran', function() {
  var albaran = $(this).val();
  var input = $(this, '.albaran');


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("AlbaranValidar", "Inicio")',
    data: {
      'Albaran': albaran
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //input.removeAttr('data-error');
      //input.removeData('error', null)
      //input.data('error', data);
      //input.attr('data-error', data);
      //input.removeData('error', null)
      //input.data('error', data);
      input.removeAttr('data-error');
      input.attr('data-error', data);
    },
    error: function(r) {
      alert("Error");
      // si falla, cambiamos el valor a 1
      input.removeAttr('data-error');
      input.attr('data-error', 1);
    }
  });
});



$(document).on('focus', '.albaran', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-error').toString()); //con este me imprimo el numero
  console.log($(this).attr('data-error')) // con este no;

  if ($(this).attr('data-error').toString() == "1") {
    console.log('entro al if del focus')
    $(this).tooltip({
      'trigger': 'focus',
      'title': 'El campo no puede estar vacio'
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="albaran" data-error="0" />
```

Comment: no me accede tampoco @AlvaroMontoro :(

Comment: @Acd he añadido una demo para que veas que sí accede bien. El único problema es que no hay `tooltip` y por eso da error en la consola, pero con los cambios que hago, ya sí lee que el valor ha cambiado a 1 (en lugar de quedarse en 0) y entra en la acción correcta. Si el código te sigue fallando puede ser por otros motivos (¿qué datos que recibes en el `success`?)

Comment: Agregue lo que devuelve a la pregunta, @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: He probado los cambios que pones en tu pregunta y mi código sigue funcionando. Prueba arriba: pon el foco en el campo, escribe lo que sea, va a entrar en el error, asignarle 1 al `data-error` y va a entrar en el `if`.

Comment: @Acd ¿cuál era el problema?

Comment: que lo estaba llamando con otro metodo focus y no veia el error porque me faltaba editarlo tambie, si me pudiera ayudar con esta pregunta te lo agradeceria

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79414/intentantdo-quitar-un-tolltip-de-boostrap-y-ponerlo-depende-del-dato-dinamicame

con esto estoy desde ayer tambien. Gracias @AlvaroMontoro