# Cambiar tooltip de Bootstrap dinámicamente

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, tooltip

Tengo un data atributo y depende de ese data atributo quiero cambiar el tooltip

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.albaran', function () {

    var albaran = $(this).val();
    var input = $(this, '.albaran');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AlbaranValidar", "Inicio")',
        data: { 'Albaran': albaran },
        success: function (data) {
            input.tooltip('title','');
            //input.removeAttr('title'); //Probe con este pero igual no me funciona.
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert("Error del servidor");
        }
    });
});
```

y acá en este evento agrego lo agrego

```
$(document).on('focus', '.albaran, .destinatario, .direccion, .cp, .provincia, .telefono, .fecha', function () {

    console.log($(this).attr('data-error').toString());
    console.log($(this).attr('data-error'));

    if ($(this).attr('data-error').toString() == "1") {
        console.log('entro al if del focus')
        $(this).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'El campo no puede estar vacio' });
    }

});
```

pero no logro cambiar el tooltip

Comment: ¿El tooltip es el de Bootstrap? ¿A qué te refieres con cambiar el tooltip?

Comment: si, o sea quitar un msj y poner otro dinamicamente

Comment: Pero de qué depende el mensaje, ¿del valor del data-atributo?

Comment: Si, tambien. parecido a la respuesta anterior que depende del data atributo cambio el tooltip @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar el atributo `title` (que será el que el tooltip use por defecto); o
2. Poner un `switch..case` con el valor del data-atributo `data-error` y seleccionar el mensaje dependiendo de eso.

El código sería algo así:

> Nota: la lógica con la que se asocia/muestra el tooltip no es del todo correcta. Se está asociando en el primer `focus` en lugar de al principio, por lo que habrá que salir y volver a entrar 2 veces para ver el tooltip.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.albaran', function() {

  var albaran = $(this).val();
  var input = $(this, '.albaran');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("AlbaranValidar", "Inicio")',
    data: {
      'Albaran': albaran
    },
    success: function(data) {
      input.removeAttr('data-error');
      input.attr('data-error', data);
    },
    error: function(r) {
      alert("Error");
      // si falla, cambiamos el valor a 1
      input.removeAttr('data-error');
      input.attr('data-error', 1);
    }
  });
});


$(document).on('focus', '.albaran, .destinatario, .direccion, .cp, .provincia, .telefono, .fecha', function() {

  var errorcode = $(this).attr('data-error').toString();
  var mensaje = "";
  
  switch(errorcode) {
    case "1": mensaje = "Error 1: bla bla bla"; break;
    case "2": mensaje = "Error 2: bla bla bla"; break;
    case "3": mensaje = "Error 3: bla bla bla"; break;
  }

  if ($(this).attr('data-error').toString() == "1") {
    console.log('entro al if del focus')
    $(this).tooltip({
      'trigger': 'focus',
      'title': mensaje,
      'placement': 'right'
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<input type="text" class="albaran" placeholder="Albaran" data-error="0" />
```

Comment: Cual cree usted que seria la logica correcta @AlvaroMontoro. Gracias por todo de verdad